# Placing SQL server in a Zend Server environment

Tags: mysql, postgresql, zend-server, zend, zend-server-ce

our developers want to migrate from individual installations of php, apache and mysql to a more integrated environment. So they decided to switch to ZendServer installed on a VMware Workstation image deployed on each developers computer.
While testing the new environment a question came up about where to place the SQL server (MySQL, PostgrSQL, SQLite).

We developed the following approaches:
Integrate it into the ZendServer VM, which seems to be the intended way as you can install MySQL together with ZendServer (Windows).
Install it locally on the developers computer.
Place it on another separate VM running in the VMware Workstation environment on the developers computer and connect via TCP or sockets(?).
Place it on a VM in our ESX based virtual infrastructure and connect via TCP.

My question is which approach would you prefer or how do you manage connections to SQL servers in your development environment? As I'm the IT guy and not a developer, I do not really know what might be the advantages/disadvantages of the above approaches from a developers perspective.

Do you know of any best practices or white papers published by Zend or others which are covering this issue?

Regards and thanks a lot!

Christian

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't depend on ZendServer or simple PHP but rather on your developers needs. Some may need to modify database structure along with codebase. Others can be comfortable with central database for all develoeprs. TCP or UNIX socket really doesn't matter while in development/testing. BTW UNIX sockets works only when client(PHP) and mysql server are on the same *NIX node.
So better to consult with developers on what they want to have.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. Most of our projects rely on a local database managed by the developer himself. So I guess an installation on the Zend Server VM would be preferable. Right?

Comment: You are totally right. I was asked the very same question by my friend developer day before you asked and we came to the same conclusion